# Remove underline for current page in menu (Twenty Twenty theme)

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, menuitem

I just changed my WP theme to Twenty Twenty. I have one primary menu on my website at the top, I just have 2 links in this menu atm. And if I am on one of the pages from the menu, it underlines that link. I'd like to remove that feature.

Website link: http://eclairblock.com

At first I tried adding this additional CSS:

```
> .primary-menu-wrapper .primary-menu .current-menu-item {text-decoration: none;}
```

But it changes nothing, If instead of `text-decoration: none`

I add for example `display: none` , then the current page link in the menu disappears.

I also tried to add `!important` but it doesn't work since the current page is still underlined in the menu.

Finally, I tried to change the style-rtf.css file by removing `.primary-menu .current_page_ancestor` from this part:

```
.primary-menu a:hover,
.primary-menu a:focus,
.primary-menu .current_page_ancestor {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

What else can I try?

Thank you guys (and sorry for being a total css noob)

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is being overridden by an existing rule that is more specific. Please try:

```
.primary-menu li.current-menu-item > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here's a guide about CSS specificity: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp